# Safari: IndexedDB: Cannot create object stores in separate transactions

Tags: javascript, safari, indexeddb

It appears that the Safari and iPhone web browsers are incapable of allowing the user to create different object stores from separate transactions. This is even the case when the user closes the database, increments the version number and then uses createObjectStore() within the onupgradedneeded callback.

Is there a workaround?

For example, visit http://bl.ocks.org/redgeoff/1dea140c52397d963377 in Safari and you'll get an alert with the "AbortError" when Safari attempts to create the 2nd object store.

For convenience, here is the same snippet of code:

```
var idb = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB
          || window.msIndexedDB;

// Generate a unique db name as IndexedDB is very delicate and we want our test
// to focus on a new DB
var dbName = 'mydb' + '_' + (new Date()).getTime() + '_'
             + Math.round(1000000*Math.random());

var db = null;

var version = 1;

var open = function (version, onSuccess, onUpgradeNeeded) {

  var request = null;
  if (version) {
    request = idb.open(dbName, version);
  } else { // 1st time opening?
    request = idb.open(dbName);
  }

  request.onupgradeneeded = function () {
    if (onUpgradeNeeded) {
      onUpgradeNeeded(request);
    }
  };

  request.onsuccess = function () {
    db = request.result;
    if (onSuccess) {
      onSuccess(request);
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function () {
    console.log('error=', request.error);
    alert('error=' + JSON.stringify(request.error));
  };
};

var createObjectStore = function (name, callback) {
  db.close(); // synchronous
  version++; // increment version to trigger onupgradeneeded
  open(version, callback, function (request) {
    request.result.createObjectStore(name, {
      keyPath: 'id'
    });
  });
};

// NOTE: we could create the first store when opening the DB for the first time, but we'll keep
// things simple and reuse our createObjectStore code for both object stores
open(null, function () {
  createObjectStore('store1', function () {
    createObjectStore('store2', function () {
      console.log('done creating both stores');
    });
  });
});
```

I tried using a sleep of 2 secs after the DB is closed and reopened and that doesn't appear to work. If there is no workaround then this essentially means that you cannot use the IndexedDB implementation in Safari to dynamically create object stores, which means that you need to know all your object stores before creating a DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken and someone has a workaround, the best way to dynamically add object stores is to implement a db-per-object-store design. In other words, you should create a new database whenever you need to create a new object store.

Another good option is to use https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim to emulate IndexedDB with WebSQL.